# comparing object attribute in one array to an object attribute in another array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object, compare

i seem to be having difficulties in accessing and comparing objects in NSMutableArrays in objective c. 
I'm very new so when explaining , some code would be nice. 
I have a character class and a characterfound class. The code looks like this:

```
@implementation character

@synthesize IDE, name;

- (void) dealloc {
    [text release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@implementation characterfound

@synthesize IDE;

- (void) dealloc {
    [text release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I have two arrays which are being filled with names and id's. 
If I want to compare just the id's to build a new array or do something else with it. 
How do I do this.

for instance

```
**character[]**
name :joe smith
IDE: ik321

name :james smith
IDE: ik32a

**characterfound[]**

IDE:2343k
IDE:ik32a
```

so when I compare the two ,the id will be found and I can put the name in another array. 
Or output it..

I'll try to refrase my question and be more specific thnx for replying btw. 
I have two classes the character class

 `@interface character : NSObject {
  // attributes 
    NSInteger type;
    NSInteger rep1, rep2, rep3, rep4, rep5;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *IDE;`

}

and the characterfound class

`@interface characterfound : NSObject {
  // attributes 
    //NSInteger IDE;
    NSInteger type;
    NSString *IDE;`

}

When I'm parsing an xml file  it encounters different tags and such and fills my characterclass accordingly

for instance

also there is some other xml in the foundcharacter like so:

so my first array will be filled with the character object including it's attributes
and the second array foundcharacter will be as well. 
**characterarray =
[character1 name="johnson" id="jfja33", character2 name="smith" id="sdfae23"]**

**characterfoundarray
[characterfound ide ="jfja33 , characterfound2 ide="jap234" ];**
So my arrays are being filled with objects and their attributes and I would like to compare the attributes( if that's possible ) and create an output.

Comment: I can't really see what the code you posted has got to do with your question. Maybe you could rephrase your question for clarity and provide relevant code.

Comment: Nobody will answer if your post is not readable! (I'm wishing I had 2000 rep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If looking up character objects by ID is a common operation, you should create a mapping from id's to character objects, at which point doing the lookup from your second array will be trivial:

```
NSMutableDictionary* charactersById = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (Character* character in characters) {
    [charactersById setObject:character forKey:[character IDE]];
}
```

(Note that I've made your class upper-case for the example code; you should do the same in your code since writing code that ignores standard language conventions is a bad idea in any language; it significantly reduces the readability of your code.)